# How to store a key and a list of strings in mybatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis

I am having trouble in mapping collection of strings to a key.

Consider a class

```
class MyClass {
  String name;
  List<String> address;
}
```

In database , name is the key which may have a list of addresses mapped to it. How do I configure this setup in mybatis and Java.

Comment: http://mybatis.co.uk/index.php/2010/10/mybatis-one-to-many-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<resultMap id="AddressMapper" type="String">
    <result property="address" column="ADDRESS" 
            javaType="String" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="MyClass" id="MyClassMapper" >
    <id column="NAME" property="name" />
    <collection resultMap="AddressMapper" property="address" />
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Hi , I have tried the above..I get the following error " Attribute "resultMap" must be declared for element type "result" " on this line
<result resultMap="addressMapper" javaType="List" />

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was wrong, I edited it. I've tried this mapping on my side, I managed to fetch **different** values for address column in a list on my side. For example: "a", "b", "c". If the returning values are same, ("a", "a"), it fetched only one row. I'm not sure why. Can you try this as well??